# Cursor style ignored when using :focus to create a CSS toggle

Tags: html, css, button, toggle

This OP is aware that a simple JavaScript `click` event would very easily suffice as an alternative to CSS here.... But curiosity craves to be satisfied:

Using the `:focus` pseudo-class can we keep the `pointer` cursor displaying when the pseudo-class is active? Have a look.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
div {
  cursor: pointer; /* div should *Always* have a pointer cursor */ 
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #0dd;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
div:focus { /* Apply this only when div is focused/clicked */
  pointer-events: none; /* pointer-events disabled to allow toggle */
  background-color: #ee0;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0"></div> <!-- tabindex allows div to be focused -->
Please click the square<br>above. Again.
```

*Notice when the div is yellow the pointer cursor changes back to it's default mouse pointer behavior?( Move the mouse ever so slightly if it doesn't )*

I want to prevent that cursor change. I want the cursor to stay in the `pointer` state throughout.

When the div is clicked an event is triggered, however the same button can not be clicked or *focused* again it seems. So clicking the yellow div would not trigger the event to revert back to blue *unless* we somehow trick the browser to think that very same click-space is an area *outside* the div. This is why the `pointer-events: none` line exists. So the toggle can be activated again and again, like a toggle should.

**My only desire is to somehow keep the pointer cursor over the yellow div without changing it's toggle behavior. This might be impossible with `pointer-events: none` but are there any ways to do this? Some type of workaround or hack?**

Comment: It isn't possible, at least not without JS.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I'm experimenting with pseudo elements and seem to be close to a solution but like you say I haven't been able to achieve it yet. What if instead of using `pointer-events` we play around with `z-index`?

Comment: I don't think `z-index` will work either, because then no click will be registered at all on the div. What you're trying to do is counter-intuitive: you're trying to block the result of a click, but keep the effect of the click. The only thing that could work is to place a transparent div directly over the one you're targeting.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb which is precisely what I'm attempting to do with `pseudo-elements` but the click events seem to be linked. I can click the pseudo element without triggering the parent but I can't click the parent without triggering the child of course... Will continue to fiddle.

Comment: what pseudo-element? it's a pseudo-selector.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Pseudo-selectors in the snippet here but I'm experimenting with pseudo-elements on codepen to place an invisible one on top of the current div but with different `:focus` properties. So far I'm having trouble.

Comment: Something `:blur` or `:focus:focus` could help :( ...

Comment: Got it! https://jsfiddle.net/8coxyjf0/

Comment: I take back my first comment :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153581/discussion-between-basement-and-tricksfortheweb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you asked for:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}
#top {
  cursor: pointer; /* div should *Always* have a pointer cursor */ 
  background-color: #0dd;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}
#top:focus { /* Apply this only when div is focused */
  pointer-events: none; /* pointer-events disabled to allow toggle */
  background-color: #ee0;
  outline: 0;
}
#top:focus + #bottom {
  pointer-events: all;
}
#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f00;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
}
```

HTML

```
<div tabindex="0" id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom" tabindex="0">
</div>
<!-- tabindex allows div to be focused -->
Please click the square<br>above. Again.
```

Comment: This is a great answer but still after all I've decided to stick with JavaScript. This is a good experimental subject delving into the limits of CSS and there's something to be learned from it.